# How would I make a 4-digit number with no repeating digits and the first digit has to be 0?

Tags: python

How would I make a 4-digit number, in which:

- only the first digit cannot be 0 (only 1-9)
- the digits are distinct from each other; no repeats of digits in the 4 digit number

I would prefer if .choice and .remove were used as I'm using a list

Comment: import random

list1=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
digit1=random.choice(list1[1:9])
digit2=list1.remove(digit1)
print(digit2)

Comment: Edit the question to show properly formatted code. Don't use comments.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the problem with it?  Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Question title doesn't seem to match your requirements - "first digit has to be 0"?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the last 3 digits using sample and then the first one using choice within the remaining digits that are between 1 and 9:

```
import random
digits = set("0123456789")
last3  = random.sample(digits,3)
first  = random.choice([*digits.difference("0",*last3)])
number = first+"".join(last3)
```

result:

```
print(number)

# '8501'
```

If you don't want to use a set, you could exclude the last 3 digits using a list comprehension:

```
digits = "0123456789"
last3  = random.sample(digits,3)
first  = random.choice([d for d in digits[1:] if d not in last3])
number = first+"".join(last3)
```

or, if you really want to go bare bone basics, just use a loop:

```
import   random
digits   = list("0123456789")
number   = ""
skipZero = 1
for i in range(4):
    digit = random.choice(digits[skipZero:])
    number += digit
    digits.remove(digit)
    skipZero = 0
```